# generic interfaces/classes and inheritance

Tags: c#-4.0, generics

I think I may be using generic interfaces inappropriately (but not sure so please tell me).  I have a small inheritance hierarchy for horse racing.  There are 3 primary interfaces : IMeeting + IRace + IRunner which I have reduced for the example.  The meeting contains races which contains runners.  I have used generics to make runtime decisions on the concrete types but it looks ugly, the WriteData method param has to declare the type for IMeeting which has to declare the type for IRace etc e.g.

```
static void WriteData(IMeeting<IRace<IRunner, string>> meeting)
```

Here is the little example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMeeting<IRace<IRunner, string>> meeting = new Meeting<IRace<IRunner, string>>();
        IRace<IRunner, string> slrace = new SL_Race<IRunner, string>();
        IRunner slrunner = new SL_Runner();
        slrace.Runners.Add(slrunner);
        meeting.Races.Add(slrace);
        WriteData(meeting);
    }

    static void WriteData(IMeeting<IRace<IRunner, string>> meeting)
    {
        // Write to db or whatever            
    }
}


public interface IMeeting<T_Race>
{
    string Course { get; set; }
    string CourseId { get; set; }
    List<T_Race> Races { get; set; }
}

public class Meeting<T_Race> : IMeeting<T_Race>
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    public List<T_Race> Races { get; set; }

    public Meeting()
    {
        Races = new List<T_Race>();
    }
}

public interface IRace<T_Runner, T_Going>
{
    T_Going Going { get; set; }
    List<T_Runner> Runners { get; set; }
}

public interface ISL_Race<T_Runner, T_Going> : IRace<T_Runner, T_Going>
{
    // Extended behaviour
    string Time { get; set; }
    string RaceId { get; set; }
    string Info { get; set; }
    uint MaxOR { get; set; }
}

public class SL_Race<T_Runner, T_Going> : ISL_Race<T_Runner, T_Going>
{
    // IRace
    public T_Going Going { get; set; }
    public List<T_Runner> Runners { get; set; }

    // ISL_RACE
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string RaceId { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public uint MaxOR { get; set; }

    public SL_Race()
    {
        Runners = new List<T_Runner>();
    }
}


public interface IRunner
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SL_Runner : IRunner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In my real world app there are a few different types of concrete runner and races.  I am trying to create a relevant meeting at runtime.  In my mind IMeeting must have a declaration for IRaces but the concrete race type can't be known until runtime and same for the runners.  My real world app also has more generic parameters and I end up with ugly looking method signatures that have to be aware of the types up the hierarchy e.g.

```
public List<IMeeting<IRP_Race<IRP_Runner, Going>>> ExtractMeetingList(String dayResultPage)
```

So am I using generics inappropriately?  I could remove all generics by moving the generic properties down to concrete classes and specify them as non generic e.g. I could move IRace.Runners to the SL_Race class, but it seems to me it should be in IRace as a race interface should have runners.

Thanks for any input.

**edit - having thought about it I should probably remove the generics and just create a subclass that has the required types that will be known at compile time e.g.

```
public interface IMeeting
{
    string Course { get; set; }
    string CourseId { get; set; }
}

// This is the new subclass with the list of concrete races "ISL_RACE"
public class ISL_Meeting : IMeeting
{
    List<ISL_Race> Races { get; set; }
}

public class SL_Meeting : ISL_Meeting
{
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string CourseId { get; set; }
    List<ISL_Race> Races {get; set;}

    public SL_Meeting()
    {
        Races = new List<ISL_Race>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with the generics? Why do you not simply use the interface types themselves? Like `public interface IMeeting
{
    List<IRace> Races { get; set; }
}` and so on?

Comment: Sorry, I missed some hierarchy in my example.  I have various classes that derive/extend IRace and their type can't be known till runtime. I would have to upcast them into IMeeting.Races and then downcast to access the extended behaviour (which I am told is bad...)

Comment: Yes, but if they have common behaviour, why is it not all listed in the common interface? And if the do not have common behaviour, why do they share an interface in the first place?

Comment: All my interfaces in the real app have extra properties that represent common behaviour. e.g for IRace '    public interface IRace<T_Runners, T_Going>
    {
        string Course { get; set; }
        string CourseId { get; set; }
        string Title { get; set; }
        string Date { get; set; }
        string Time { get; set; }
        string Uri { get; set; }
        List<T_Runners> Runners { get; set; }
    }' Its the extended behaviour that prevents me using Irace for type in IMeeting.Races. Like I say, I could move Races down to a concrete class.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus - I think you are probably right, I have a poor design.  I was trying to show intent that an IMeeting should have something representing "races".  The generics seems like a sledgehammer to the problem.